# Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is deprecated. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)`

Tags: php, laravel-6

**Hi I'm stuck on this error message. I tried to encapsulate it with parenthesis still I got an error on this specific line.**

```
<div class="form-group">
 {!! Form::label('parent_id','Parent') !!}
 {!! General::selectMultiLevel('parent_id', $categories, ['class' => 'form-control', 'selected' => !empty(old('parent_id')) ? old('parent_id') : !empty($category['parent_id']) ? $category['parent_id'] : '', 'placeholder'=>'---Chose Category---' ]) !!}
```

Comment: How are the ternary's suppose to be written? Please define some logic. These look stacked which manual recommends not doing. `It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious` https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `old('parent_id') ?? $category['parent_id'] ?? ''`

```
 {!! General::selectMultiLevel('parent_id', $categories, ['class' => 'form-control', 'selected' => old('parent_id') ?? $category['parent_id'] ?? '', 'placeholder'=>'---Chose Category---' ]) !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to nested ternaries, which in my opinion is extremely difficult to read!

As the message states, avoid nested ternaries where precedence is not enforced by parenthesis.

From your code:

```
{!! General::selectMultiLevel('parent_id', $categories, [
'class' => 'form-control', 
'selected' => !empty(old('parent_id')) ? old('parent_id') : !empty($category['parent_id']) ? $category['parent_id'] : '', 
'placeholder'=>'---Chose Category---' ]) 
!!}
```

The issue lies within the 'selected' key. replacing

```
!empty(old('parent_id')) ? old('parent_id') : !empty($category['parent_id']) ? $category['parent_id'] : ''
```

with

```
!empty(old('parent_id')) ? old('parent_id') : (!empty($category['parent_id']) ? $category['parent_id'] : '')
```

Notice the additional parenthesis after the first :

But maybe consider using complete if statements for nested blocks for readability.